# Notedpad++ NppFTP plugin retrieval of passwords

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way we can retrieve passwords saved for FTP accounts under NppFTP plugin with Notepad++?

Thank you.
Jae

Answer (score 23):

There is one way but you must put some effort:

1. Download Wireshark http://www.wireshark.org/ (program for network monitoring)
2. After installation, open it as administrator
3. Click: Capture->Interfaces
4. Choose interface which has some packets (you will see them if you wait on this screen for a while) and click Start
5. Open Notepad++ and connect to FTP of your choice
6. Go back to the wireshark and click stop (4th button on the left)
7. Inside filter field type: ftp
8. Your password will be listed among other stuff about this FTP connection (check out the Info column for Request: PASS)

It's not an easy solution but it's good for every FTP program not only Npp

Comment: Mister, you saved my life! Please accept my humble upvote.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

It is in `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\plugins\Config\NppFTP\NppFTP.xml` however the passwords are hashed somehow.

Comment: It supposed to be a reversible hash or maybe an index into a database based on the same length.

Comment: re: "supposed to be a reversible hash" -- it is DES 64-bit Cipher Feedback. See: RFC 2948 : http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2948.txt for details.  The default master password is "NppFTP00" (or what you gave instead) and is used as the KEY for decrypting the hashed password for connections in that file.

Comment: @JesseChisholm, thanks, but, first, standard 2948 refers to an OFB mode of DES, not a CFB mode, and second, for either, what's used for the IV?

Comment: Then, to be even more specific, NppFTP uses the DES algorithms in OpenSSL.  Here is someones code for this: https://gist.github.com/alecgorge/1623895 which you are right, is RFC 2947, not 2948 : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2947